# ImportError: cannot import name 'ss'

Tags: python-3.x, statsmodels

Here is my code:

```
from neurosynth import Dataset
from neurosynth import meta, decode, network
```

I keep getting the error ImportError: cannot import name 'ss'.

I have tried updating SciPy, pandas, and statsmodels but I still get the error. I think the problem has something to do with how I installed anaconda and pip.

Here is the Traceback Call:

```
ImportError  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-ae43d8021cee> in <module>()
   1 from neurosynth import Dataset 
   2 from neurosynth import meta, decode, network 

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/neurosynth/__init__.py in <module>()
  9 from .base.dataset import Dataset
 10 from .base.mask import Masker
 11 from .analysis.cluster import Clusterable
 12 from .analysis.meta import MetaAnalysis
 13 from .analysis.decode import Decoder

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/neurosynth/analysis/cluster.py in <module>()
  8 from os import makedirs
  9 from nibabel import nifti1
 10 from neurosynth.analysis import meta
 11 
 12 

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/neurosynth/analysis/meta.py in <module>()
  5 from scipy.stats import norm
  6 from neurosynth.base import imageutils
  7 from neurosynth.analysis import stats
  8 from os.path import join, exists
  9 from os import makedirs

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/neurosynth/analysis/stats.py in <module>()
  4 import numpy as np
  5 from scipy import special
  6 from scipy.stats import ss
  7 
  8 

ImportError: cannot import name 'ss'
```

Comment: Which package is raising the error. Python produces informative tracebacks that are very helpful when asking this type of question. statsmodels 0.8 had the incompatibility with recent scipy, but that is (should be) fixed in statsmodels 0.9.

Comment: The package is scipy. I just add the traceback call in the question if you want to look.

Comment: The problem is in `neurosynth` according to the traceback. You need to update the version or file a bug report if they haven't adjusted yet to recent scipy. As workaround you could monkey patch scipy.stats until you get the neurosynth fixed.

Comment: https://github.com/neurosynth/neurosynth/commit/8b4662159b1ce3cc903c96068536554e3861ee09#diff-34b734d72a8eadc56a6f0e9c4aa8427e

Comment: Thanks! I am going to file a bug report. I tried updating the version and it still didn't work